# how can i set Hyperlink shared folder address with java

Tags: java, excel, hyperlink

My java program make excel file, And Set Hyperlink a cell.
It setted address homepage address like http://~~
But I have to change this to shared folder address like \150.11.54.1\TestFolder

But it make happen error "must be a valid uri" since I changed link to folder path.

This is my source.

```
Hyperlink  link = ch.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_URL);
link.setAddress("\\\\150.17.xxx.xxx\\TestFolder");
```

*Hyperlink = org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Hyperlink

I tried to change from LINK_URL to LINK_FILE or LINK_DIRECTORY
But it couldn't solve problem.

Please teach me if you know solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer myself.
very simple solution.
link.setAddress("file:////150.17.xxx.xxx//TestFolder");

Be carefull that This is wrong.
file:\\150.17.xxx.xxx\TestFolder